# Auto populate the RD (Rest Days) in attendance tracker using Excel 2013

Tags: excel

I have an attendance tracker for employees.  I put their rest days in Column C.  Lets' say Rest Day for agent A are Sunday and Monday, I wanted to have a text "RD" display on  every a cell which is Sun and Mon rather than manually typing the text "RD".  I will put a screenshot here.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4C9C.png)

Comment: What have you tried? It looks straightforward using FIND or SEARCH to see if the current weekday is in the list of rest days for a particular person.

Comment: Thanks Tom.  As of now, I never tried anything yet.  I was thinking if I can use the if function to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would look like this, where C$2 is the day of the week e.g. "Sun" and $B3 is the off days e.g. "Sat-Sun"

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(C$2,$B3)),"RD","")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Sir Tom Sharpe, thank you so much for your quick response and yes it really works for me..100 %...